# Como es la sintaxis correcta para hacer un UPDATE en MongoDB Compass?

Tags: mongodb

estoy practicando consultas en Mongo DB Compass, soy totalmente nuevo. Queria saber como es la sintaxis correcta para poder hacer un UPDATE y DELETE con la consola _MONGOSH.

```
{ _id: ObjectId("62a5e794ec7d1be622789046"),
  CODIGOMATERIA: 1,
  NOMBREMATEIRA: 'BASE DE DATOS',
  DIACURSADA: 'LUNES',
  DOCENTES: 
   [ { Nombre: 'Tomas', Titular: 'Si' },
     { Nombre: 'Juan', Titular: 'No' } ],
  Notas: [ 10, 9 ] }
```

Esta es la colección que tengo ya insertada.

Para hacer el UPDATE eh intentado:

```
db.materias.updateOne({DIACURSADA: "LUNES"}, {set: {DIACURSADA: "MARTES"}});

db.materias.updateOne({DIACURSADA: "LUNES"}, {DIACURSADA: "MARTES"});

db.materias.updateOne({DIACURSADA: "LUNES"}, {set: DIACURSADA: "MARTES"});

  { _id: "62a5e794ec7d1be622789046"},
   {
     $push: { DIACURSADA: { by: "MARTES"} }
   }
)
```

Pero tengo el siguiente error:

> MongoInvalidArgumentError: Update document requires atomic operators

Como es la sintaxis correcta para hacer un UPDATE?

Comment: Es `$set`. Estás usando sólo `set`. Ese es el problema principal. Saludos

Comment: Si, me faltaba el signo de $

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la solución que encontré

db.materias.update({"DIACURSADA": "LUNES"},{$set: {"DIACURSADA": "MARTES"}})